# Parse text, pick value after `:` colon, trimming surrounding whitespace

Tags: perl, bash, awk

I'd like to establish a best way to do "something" and consider it a tool in my shell scripting arsenal.

**"Something": parse a line of text, get value after delimiter, trim surrounding whitespace**

---

#### Example:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
```

---

I'd like to get out `Ubuntu 12.10` (basically, what follows the `:` separator) and nothing else, particularly no surrounding whitespace, including the newline character.

---

I cannot decide among:

1 [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
$ lsb_release -d | awk -F':[[:blank:]]*' '{print $2}'
Ubuntu 12.10
```

2 [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

```
$ lsb_release -d | perl -F':\s*' -lane 'print $F[1]'
Ubuntu 12.10
```

3 [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

```
$ v=$(lsb_release -d); printf "${v/*:[[:blank:]]/}\n"
Ubuntu 12.10
```

4 something else, better written, that you can recommend here

---

I am looking for something *pure*, written as well as one can in the language of choice.

In this light, I am *particularly disappointed* in what I could come up with in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), which is a shell language I am trying to study, but I could do no better than that. `☹` I cannot explain, for instance, why the substitution replaces multiple blanks even if there is no pattern repetition specified, **can you**?

You'll probably come up with more terse and elegant ways than my `1.`, `2.` and `3.` - that's great. An opportunity for me to learn.

---

*Reason for asking: I am doing a lot of self-learning these days, and I am saving info in* `Key: Value` *format in text files.. it really helps to find a* **great** *way to grab the stuff after the first colon. At the moment, text configuration files are the best I can do. It'll change :)*

---

PS: I can't wait to move over to [java](/questions/tagged/java), and be able to use Commons Configuration (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) and move out of these `Key: Value` formats I am using now..

---

#### Assumptions:

- be able to simply specify separator
- separator to be followed by 0..N blanks (tabs, spaces, etc.)
- rest of line parsed out and returned, no newline
- result as single string (i.e. in [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) not separate words)

Comment: "I cannot explain, for instance, why the substitution replaces multiple blanks even if there is not pattern repetition specified." I just tested this, and at least for me it only replaced one blank.

Comment: You are right, it's just 0x09, which is a `\t`, and it looked like more. I got confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I personally go for awk as a first recourse for this sort of thing, the code you use there is perhaps not as general as you'd like. In particular, by setting the field separator as you've done, you run the risk of it getting recognized on the right-hand side of your property lines, making `$2` not actually be the full property value. I think you'd probably be better off avoiding using FS at all and doing something like the following, which operates on the full original line(s):

```
awk '{ sub(/^[^:]*:[:blank:]*/, ""); print }'
```

which is the slightly abbreviated version of:

```
awk '{ sub(/^[^:]*:[:blank:]*/, "", $0); print $0; }'
```

That is, remove (replace with the empty string) from the line (`$0`) everything up to the first colon followed by zero or more blanks. Print the result.

For a bash version, I'd use the match operator available in `[[` expressions. The variable name you have to use for extracted sub-expressions is a bit verbose, but I like that I can use less quirky (or at least the usual expected quirks of) regular expression syntax:

```
[[ $v =~ ^[^:]*:[:blank:]*(.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

The regex here is mostly the same as the one used in the awk version above.

Comment: Absolutely awesome. Very elegant `awk` and _inspiring_ use of `bash`'s automatic regex capture group `(...)` assignments to `BASH_REMATCH`! Nice to use the shortcut conditional `&&` in place of an `if` statement and nice to leverage unquoted regex patterns on the right of `=~`. If I may, most humbly, add something of my own: you don't actually need the quotes around `"$v"` as it's inside and on the left of a `[[`, where no word-splitting occurs (`man bash`). Thanks! You **rock**!

Comment: Thanks! I'm on the fence about whether to go with always double quoting variables, because it's less cognitive load than trying to remember where you can do what, or always going for minimal keystrokes. I'll edit per your suggestion.

Comment: And FWIW for the same "cognitive load" reason I tend to use `${name}` syntax consistently in my bash code, even when not strictly necessary.

Comment: I used to be like you, always using `${name}`, even when not necessary. Less "cognitive load" is a perfect definition. There is something unnerving about the asymmetry between `$a` and `${b[i]}`. Vim also (often) does nicer syntax highlighting on `${c}` than `$c`. Today, though, I do without the unnecessary characters. SO feedback influenced me. And now I influence you, somebody who thinks like I did! :) Ah, groupthink..

Answer (score 3):

Another Perl version:

```
lsb_release -d | perl -pe 's/^[^:]*:\s*//;s/\s*$//;'
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks.. upvoting! (you forgot the `-d`)

Answer (score 1):

Perl has a [module available](https://metacpan.org/module/Config%3a%3aProperties%3a%3aCommons) to parse Commons Configuration files. As an (overengineered) one-liner:

```
lsb_release -d | perl -MConfig::Properties::Commons -E'say Config::Properties::Commons->new(load_file=>\*STDIN)->get_property("Description")'
```

As a normal script:

```
#!perl
use strict; use warnings; use 5.010;

use Config::Properties::Commons;

my $cpc = Config::Properties::Commons->new;
$cpc->load($ARGV[0] // \*STDIN);

say $cpc->get_property("Description");
```

Without that module, I would use `split`:

`split /:\s*/, $_` would split on any colon and remove all following whitespace,
`split /:\s*/, $_, 2` will split the string into two pieces max (so the value can include colons),
and `(split /:\s*/, $_, 2)[1]` will return the second fragment. Therefore

```
lsb_release -d | perl -lne's/\s*$//, print for (split /:\s*/, $_, 2)[1]'
```

would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this could still be considered a one-liner:

```
lsb_release -d|php -r "echo trim(end(explode(':', file_get_contents('php://stdin'), 2)));"
```

Sadly PHP doesn't have a shorthand to handle fetching from `stdin` ;-)

Comment: It's a nice one but when running two pipes in a row I always ask myself.. could one of the commands not do what the one before or after it does _as well_? (one less interpreter to fire up/subshell to fork..)

Comment: @Robottinosino Replaced it with PHP instead =D

Comment: Nice to see `PHP` in here! Upvoting as a welcome to the language, rarely used in CLI.

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want to actually *parse* text like you described, you could use [YAML::XS](https://metacpan.org/module/YAML%3a%3aXS).

```
$ lsb_release -d | perl -MYAML::XS -E'local $/;say Load(<>)->{Description}'
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
```

```
$ perl -MYAML::XS -MData::Printer -E'p Load(do{local $/;<>})'
key1: value1
key2: value2
^d
\ {
    key1   "value1",
    key2   "value2"
}
```

(`^d` represents pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>)

The output of [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aPrinter) is actually more colorful than can be reproduced here.

Comment: I very much like these solutions and I thank you for sharing them! I am upvoting the versatility of them but you will agree that those `perl` modules aren't installed by default on a non- perl dev box and so I am probably better off learning a more "widely applicable" solution? Upvoting the "lesson in perl" though :)

Comment: CPAN is one of the most valuable features of Perl. Why write code that other people have already written? CPAN is a huge collection of easily installable modules, just waiting for you to use them.